# In Ruby, how to write code inside a class so that getter foo and setter self.foo = ... look more similar?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, inside a class's instance method, we use a getter by

```
foo
```

and we use a setter by

```
self.foo = something
```

One doesn't need to have a `self.` and the other does, is there a way to make them look more similar, and not using something like `self.foo` as the getter, as it also looks verbose.

(update: note that getter and setter may simply get or set an instance variable, but they might also do a lot of work, such as going into the DB and check the existence of a record and if not, create it, etc)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since local scope takes precedence, when you say `foo = something`, a local variable `foo` will be created and assigned the contents of `something`.

The reason you can write `foo` in order to use the getter is because Ruby will move up in scope when it can't find a variable with that name and it will eventually find the method.

If there is a local variable with the same name as the getter method, Ruby will use its value instead:

```
class Foo

  attr_accessor :foo

  def initialize
    @foo = :one
  end

  def f
    foo = :two
    foo
  end
end

Foo.new.f
# => :two
```

In order to make it clear that you want to access the setter, you must write `self.foo = something`. That will tell Ruby you want to execute the `foo=` method on the `self` object with `something` as parameter.

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to break the conventions, you can write your setters using jQuery style, using the same method for getter and setter, depending of whether it has arguments or not:

```
def foo *args
  return @foo if args.empty?
  @foo = args.first
end
# => nil

foo
# => nil 
foo(:bar) # foo = :bar
# => :bar 
foo
# => :bar
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a way around this in Ruby. I'm pretty confident this is simply how Ruby evaluates expressions.

When given a value, Ruby will first check if there is a local variable within the context which matches the one being called. If there is (perhaps 'foo' in your case), that will be the value used. If there is no such value, then Ruby will try to look up the value as a method call (falling through to "self" as the caller). If no such method exists in the look up path, an error will be raised.

The need to use "self" in the setter is to avoid Ruby setting the value as a local variable, while the lack of the use of "self" only works in the getter instance when there is no local variable of the same name being used in that context. It is probably better and clearer, albeit slightly more verbose, to be explicit with your use of self as to avoid confusion about where values are coming from.