# Setting attribute from model without using self doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions, self

Device model has following attributes: name, version and full_name

Full name is name + version:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  def prepare
    full_name = (!show_version || version.nil?)? name : name + " " + version.to_s
  end
end
```

When i do following:

```
d = Device.new :name => "iPhone", :version => "4"
d.prepare
d.full_name # get nil
```

I get nil for "full_name" attribute

When I'm using "self", it works:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  def prepare
    self.full_name = (!show_version || version.nil?)? name : name + " " + version.to_s
  end
end
```

Doing "prepare" i get "iPhone 4" for "full_name" attribute.

Some people here told me, that it's a good manner to avoid using "self" inside class methods.
But this brings trouble.

The question is - why it does't works without using "self" ?

Answer (score 16):

In these cases you have to use self, I don't think it's a trouble. If you are using `self` then the interpreter will know that you refer to the object's attribute. If you don't use `self` it means that it's just an local variable which is not stored anywhere after the method finishes.That's the normal behavior. You can also use `self[:full_name]= ...` as a setter method, but in this case doesn't really matter.

**Update**

@AntonAL

Because the getter methods are recognized without the `self.`.

When you try to use the `name` attribute, the interpreter will look for a local variable within the current method. If doesn't finds then looks for an instance attribute. Example:

```
def your_method
  self.name = 'iPhone'
  puts name
  #iPhone
  name = 'iPod'
  puts name
  #iPod
  puts self.name
  #iPhone
end
```

And `iPhone` will be stored in your object instance's `name` attribute. And `iPod` will be lost after the method finishes.

Comment: You're correct on the definition, but it's a local variable, not an instance variable.

Comment: OK, but why it does't works without self? Following to "interpreters logic", it should use model's method, when i tell him "full_name = ...", because there is no "full_name" local or global variables. Why "name" and "version" are interpreted as instance attributes, but not as local variables ?

Comment: @antonal..`name` and `version` will also be interpreted as local variables and when it doesnt find local variables defined, it will look for a method defined. And if it doesnt find a method, it will raise `undefined local variable or method` error. The problem with `full_name = ` is that we can define a new non existing local variable with the same syntax.

Answer (score 13):

When you use setters, you need to use `self` because otherwise Ruby will interpret it as a new local variable `full_name` being defined.

For getters, we dont need to call `self` because Ruby first search for a local variable `full_name` and when it does not have a local variable `full_name`, it will search for a method `full_name` and will get the getter. If you have a local variable defined `full_name`, it will return the value of local variable.

This is explained better in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367254/in-ruby-how-to-write-code-inside-a-class-so-that-getter-foo-and-setter-self-foo)

Comment: Wow, this is so confusing in Ruby.  Today I got weird problems using setter inside a class, and it turns out what you explained !!!!!!

Comment: @PeterLee..it is better to explicitly use `self` for both getter and setter, to make it more uniform.

Comment: @rubyprince following that rule, would it be good to use self for associations as well? I just like things parallel.

Comment: @gwho. Now I do not use `self` for getters, but only for setters as I now follow this [styleguide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) (Part of it is due to code review tools such as [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) which insists on not using `self`, unless it is necessary. We are now as a team following this styleguide). 

But when I used `self` for getters, I actually used `self` for associations also to make it uniform all across.

Comment: So whether it's associations or attributes, use `self` for setters, but not getters.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because it's how ActiveRecord works by design. If you need to set arbitrary attributes, then you have to use a different kind of objects.

For example, Ruby provides a library called

> OpenStruct

that allows you to create objects where you can assign arbitrary key and values. If you want get value from attribute without self, it's will give you instance of class OpenStruct with instance global variable attribute. But if you want set new attribute, it`s create new instance of class OpenStruct with new attributes. Without self you will have are old OpenStruct object which don't have attribute and will gave you error.

You may want to use such library and then convert the object into a corresponding ActiveRecord instance only when you need to save to the database.

Don't try to model ActiveRecord to behave as you just described because it was simply not designed to behave in that way